# native query unable to set parameter while creating partition

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, nativequery

I have the following query to create a partition, it's working with hardcoded values but is unable to replace parameters dynamically.

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "CREATE TABLE :name PARTITION OF sample_table\n"
        + "FOR VALUES FROM (a) TO (b)", nativeQuery = true)
void createPartition(@Param("name") String name, @Param("a") long a, @Param("b") long b);
```

This statement I want to generate which is working fine on postgres console:

```
CREATE TABLE sample_table_p1 PARTITION OF sample_table
        FOR VALUES FROM ('1020000') TO ('2000000');
```

error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can't pass an identifier as a parameter. You need to dynamically create the SQL string with an explicit identifier

Comment: how can we pass the SQL query string to value? @a_horse_with_no_name